# How can I avoid encoding errors using Net::OpenID::Consumer with Yahoo OpenIDs?

Tags: perl, openid, yahoo, dancer

I've written a Dancer web app that utilizes `Net::OpenID::Consumer` to consume OpenIDs for authentication.  It works well with Google and MyOpenID, but not Yahoo. When a user tries to authenticate using their Yahoo account, `HTML::Parser` warns:

> `Parsing of undecoded UTF-8 will give garbage when decoding entities`

and this warning kills my app (rightfully so).

I don't see any existing bugs with `Net::OpenID::Consumer` (or Common) that relate to this. 
The HTTP headers and the HTML meta tags both specify UTF-8 for the 'claimed id' URI.
Why would the response not be decoded for `HTML::Parser`? Am I missing something obvious?

Here's the relevant code:

```
get '/openid_landing' => sub {
    my $params = params();
    my $csr = Net::OpenID::Consumer->new(
        ua => LWP::UserAgent->new(),
        consumer_secret => $secret,
        params => $params,
    );  
    my $id = $params->{'openid.claimed_id'};

    if (my $setup_url = $csr->user_setup_url) {
        redirect $setup_url;

    } elsif ($csr->user_cancel) {
        redirect uri_for('/');

    } elsif (my $vident = $csr->verified_identity) {
       # verified identity, log in or register user
       ...

    } else {
        die "Error validating identity: " . $csr->err;
    } 
};
```

Comment: [Show your code](http://sscce.org) so that people may [reproduce the problem](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html#showmehow).

Comment: Sounds like you didn't decode the HTML before passing it to Parser, so decode it. If this was LWP, I'd say use `->decoded_content` instead of `->content`.

Comment: user1215106, Net::OpenId::Common is grabbing and parsing the HTML, not my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is in **Net/OpenID/URIFetch.pm** on lines 122-128 of version 1.14 (latest)
It's using the raw content instead of the decoded content of the response object.
Just remove the manual gzip decoding and use the decoded_content method in the response.

I haven't filed a bug report yet, feel free. :)

Here's a diff you can apply to fix it:

```
122c122
<         my $content = $res->decoded_content;
---
>         my $content = $res->content;
125a126,129
>         if ($res->content_encoding && $res->content_encoding eq 'gzip') {
>             $content = Compress::Zlib::memGunzip($content);
>         }
>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I'll file a bug report on this soon and will link this post.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the HTML::Parser module that is used by TreeBuilder under the hood, before you passing the page contents to TreeBuilder, feed them through decode_utf8:

```
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use Encode;
my $contents = ...;
my $htree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content(decode_utf8 $contents);
```

For more :

[http://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder#new-from-content](http://metacpan.org/pod/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder#new-from-content)

http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Parser/Parser.pm